# Angular downgrade from 7 to 6

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7

Пишу проект на Angular 7.
Параллельно нужно нужно начать проект на Angular 6.
Я так понимаю, что нужно удалить CLI и установить ее шестую версию.
Не сломает это проект на 7 версии?

Как правильнее сделать?

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache clean --force
npm install -g @angular/cli@6.2.5
```

Comment: зачем вам переустанавливать глобальную версию если вы можете создать проект используя 7 версию и в этом проекте просто даунгрейднуть версию пакетов до 6?

Comment: Да, согласен, не с той стороны зашел